# can someone help me with my java assignment?

Tags: java

Hello can someone help me resolve the issue that I'm facing:

For some reason it will not move after the hoursEntered() operation. I would like it to go to the if else block

```
package Exercises;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class ParkingCharges {

    static Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    static double minimum_fee = 2.0;
    static double maximum_fee = 10.0;
    static double extra_per_HourCharge = 0.50;
    int daily_hours;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Display();
        hoursEntered();
        if (hoursEntered() <= 0.0 || hoursEntered() >24) {
            System.out.println("Invalid hours entered. Valid hours are 1 through 24");
            Display();
            hoursEntered();
        }
        if (hoursEntered() <= 3.0) {
            System.out.println("Minimum number of hours parked" + minimum_fee);
        } else {
            extraCharge();
        }
    }

    static void Display() {
        System.out.println(" Enter the number of hours parked: ");
    }

    public static double hoursEntered() {
        double numberOfHours = input.nextDouble();
        System.out.println(numberOfHours);
        return numberOfHours;
    }

    public static double extraCharge() {
        double extraChargeAmount = 0.0;
        extraChargeAmount = minimum_fee + (hoursEntered() - 3)*extra_per_HourCharge;
        if (extraChargeAmount >= 10.0) {
            extraChargeAmount = 10;
            return extraChargeAmount;
        } else {
            return extraChargeAmount;
        }
    }
}
```

This program will not move to the next steps for some reason ??

Comment: Please format your code, then paste it to the stack overflow editor and click the "{}" button so it appears like a real program :)

Comment: Please visit the [help] and take some time to learn about this site and how to ask questions.  In general, you are expected to have made an effort to solve the problem, and also  tell us what you have done.  In this case I'd advise you to step through the code in an IDE (Eclipse, NetBeans, etc) and examine variables at the points where it is not doing what you expect.

Comment: Thanks Jim....Sorry kind'a new to this and yes I will go through the Help Center

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See comments in the code:

```
    import java.util.Scanner;

    public class ParkingCharges {

        static Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        static double minimum_fee = 2.0;
        static double maximum_fee = 10.0;
        static double extra_per_HourCharge = 0.50;
        int daily_hours;

        public static void main(String[] args) {
            Display();
            //as Alexandro Sifuentes Díaz suggested
            double hoursParked = hoursEntered();

            //change if (that runs once) to  a loop
            while ((hoursParked <= 0.0) || (hoursParked >24)) {
                System.out.println("Invalid hours entered. Valid hours are 1 through 24");
                Display();
                hoursParked = hoursEntered();
            }

            if (hoursParked <= 3.0) {
                System.out.println("Minimum number of hours parked, fee is: " + minimum_fee);
            } else {
                //obtain and output the parking charge  
                System.out.println("Parking fee is " +extraCharge(hoursParked));

            }
        }

        static void Display() {
            System.out.println(" Enter the number of hours parked: \n");
        }

        public static double hoursEntered() {
            double numberOfHours = input.nextDouble();
            System.out.println(numberOfHours);
            return numberOfHours;
        }

        //use hoursParked obtained earlier
        public static double extraCharge(double hoursParked) {
            double extraChargeAmount = 0.0;
            extraChargeAmount = minimum_fee + ((hoursParked - 3)*extra_per_HourCharge);
            if (extraChargeAmount >= 10.0) {
                extraChargeAmount = 10;
                //removed un needed return and else else
            }
             return extraChargeAmount;

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You call many times `hoursEntered()`, just call it once:

```
double hour = hoursEntered();
if (hour <= 0.0 || hour > 24) {
    ...
    hoursEntered(); // <--- why?
} else if (hour <= 3.0) {
   ...
else {
    extraCharge(hour);
}
```

And in the extraCharge() method, just send this value:

```
public static double extraCharge(double hour) {
    ...
    extraChargeAmount = minimum_fee + (hour - 3)*extra_per_HourCharge;
    ...
}
```

And I guess you should recode your function to allow recursion (because I think you will ask the user to input a valid hour an undefined amount of times).